# Implementing RSA in C# when Public Key is Known

Tags: c#, rsa, public-key

I'm trying to implement an RSA encryption function, but I'm new to cryptography. I know the public key and have data to encrypt, but I can't get the implementation correct in C#. I've tried using:

```
private byte[] RSAEncrypt(byte[] data, byte[] publicKey)
{
    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = RSA.ExportParameters(false);
        RSAKeyInfo.Modulus = publicKey;
        RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);
        data = RSA.Encrypt(data, false);
    }

    return data;
}
```

But this keeps giving me the error "Bad Length". The public key is 8 bytes long. The data is 254 bytes long. The similar questions about that error say that it occurs when the data is too long. Does an 8 byte long public key sound correct to encrypt 254 bytes?

Comment: I can't tell whether you are asking a technical question about the .NET framework (and in such case should take it stackoverflow or a Microsoft support forum), or whether you want to know what the problem with a 64 RSA key encrypting 2016 bits of plain text might be from a more general point of view (and in such case should put more emphasis on the last paragraph). Please advise.

Comment: Updated question. I don't really know enough about RSA encryption to figure out the parameters.

Comment: There are probably multiple things going wrong here (e.g. 8-byte RSA public key is way too short to be secure), some of which are off topic here because they are about using that API rather than about RSA generally. [This](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/does-rsa-work-for-any-message-m) might be a partial duplicate for the data > modulus issue, but padding may also be involved.

Comment: The 254 bytes are padded.

Comment: Your code looks fine, but the input is almost certainly wrong. 8 byte for a public key is simply not possible. You wouldn't even be able to encrypt a symmetric key with it.

Comment: Ok, I suppose that's what I needed to know. I'm getting the wrong values for a public key. I'll go back to the drawing board. Thanks.

Comment: Where did you get that public key? I think you're mistaking the shortened "public key token" (used for quick human identification) for the *actual* public key (which would be more like 128 bytes).

Comment: I'm trying to implement the Telegram API in C#. I'm on step 4 described here: https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/samples-auth_key#4-generatsiya-encrypted-data. I've already done the SHA1 hash, and am trying to figure out RSA. In step 2, it says the "fingerprints" are the public server key, but it is only 8 bytes long.

Comment: @JesseMcConahie: The public key *fingerprint* is 8 bytes but the public key modulus itself is 256 bytes. I believe you will have grab the public modulus from one of the open source clients, such as [this one](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram).